# Control Popover antd by button but still keep default behavior

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

I want to control the Popover Antd using a button, which means I can show and hide the popover by clicking the button. Additionally, I want to retain its default behavior, so when I click on the content, the popover will show up and be hidden when I click outside of it. Thank you so much.

Comment: The question you asked is too generic, we can help with only specific problems with code attached. Please follow the [Stackoveflow: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you can get proper help.

Comment: You need to use a state and connect your popover with using `open` and `onOpenChange` prop to handle popover visibility. You can follow this [Example](https://ant.design/components/popover#components-popover-demo-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the Popover component in Ant Design (Antd) using a button, you can use the `visible` prop of the Popover to conditionally show or hide it based on the state of a button click. Additionally, to retain the default behavior of showing the Popover when clicking on the content and hiding it when clicking outside, you can use the `trigger` prop with the value "click" for the Popover.

App.jsx

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Popover } from 'antd';

const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  // Function to toggle the visibility of the Popover
  const handleTogglePopover = () => {
    setVisible(!visible);
  };

  // Content to be displayed inside the Popover
  const content = (
    <div>
      <p>This is the content of the Popover</p>
      <p>Clicking inside the Popover won't hide it.</p>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Popover
        content={content}
        visible={visible}
        trigger="click" // Show the Popover on click of the content
        onVisibleChange={(visible) => setVisible(visible)} // Update the state when the visibility changes
      >
        <Button onClick={handleTogglePopover}>Toggle Popover</Button>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```